# java formatter for eclipse and intellij

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, formatter

My teammates are using eclipse and intellij simultaneously. So are having very frequent merge issues because of formatting styles. Is there any formatter available which will produce same result from both eclipse and intellij. Google's formatter is there for both but I am not sure if it will produce same result from both.

Comment: [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) seems to be emerging as a standard that most IDEs honor.

Comment: I don't see your problem. Your team defines say an eclipse formatting rule file. Then you use that with Intellij. If you are not doing too complicated things, that works out of the box. The only thing you have to adapt on top of that is the order for organizing imports. But getting to "same formatting style" with both IDEs can be achieved within maybe 10 minutes, and 5 minutes of that are reading documentation.

Comment: The Eclipse formatter can be invoked from the command line (for the intellij folks)

Answer (score 3):

There is [Eclipse Code Formatter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter) plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA.